# withFormik how to access wrapped form's props in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I define:

```
class Form1 extends React.Component{
....
}
```

and then define the HOC using withFormic:

```
const Form2 = withFormik({
  handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {
    ...
  },
....
})(Form1);
```

In the parent component, I specify a callback function:

```
<Task2 callback={this.something} />
```

Now, I want the handleSubmit to call the callback function.
I would do just

```
this.props.callback()
```

but it seems that `this` is not defined in the HOC.

**Question: how can I access the Form1.props within the HOC?**

Comment: I still haven't found an answer, but there is a workaround: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/312

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass props as one of the second argument in `handleSubmit` and you can access props as below:

```
const Form2 = withFormik({
handleSubmit(values, { props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {
...
props.callback();
},
....
})(Form1);
```